# Codeigniter/Facebook SDK logic about login

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

Ok guys I'm creating an application in CodeIgniter that utilizes the Facebook SDK, both PHP and JS. It will be a user platform will people earn rewards etc. for sharing. What I'm confused about is the authentication for my application. So when a user comes to my site and logs in, do they need to authenticate every time? Can I store credentials? Should I only log them in with facebook. I guess to me it seems like they have to authenticate every time. How would you suggest integrating the authentication into the login process? I want to make calls like gathering info etc. but I want them to just authenticate one time and that's it.

I'm using calls like this from the sparks facebook SDK

```
 $user_profile = $this->facebook->api('/me');
```

which basically works when the oAuth happens. how can I make this happen with out making them click through to facebook every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine it with the login process, that seems to be a better choice for your needs. You can store the non-expiring offline access token returned by facebook and save it into the database

P.S. They are deprecating the offline access token but you can use it for now. After deprecation, you can probably get an extended access token which is valid for 6 months)